# What is correct use of 's

Tags: phrases

My father gifted me a car.

Having that context in mind, is it correct to write the statement below?

> "Father's Gift"

There are two meanings to this statement.

1. I gifted a car to my father
2. father gifted me a car.

What is the correct way to write this?

Comment: The statement "Father's gift" simply states that the father possesses a gift (in this case a car). It says nothing about any action performed on that gift, either giving or receiving.

Comment: <<Father's gift>> is correctly formed but, as you say, is ambiguous, meaning either 'the gift from my father [to X] / secured by my father to be given to X' **or** 'the gift to / intended for my father [from / secured by X]'. This ambiguity does not stop the expression being commonly and perfectly acceptably used in either sense. Context will usually disambiguate, but you are right in that unresolved ambiguities need resolving.

Comment: A _statement_ would have to be something like "The car was my father's gift to me", in which case the rest of the sentence makes the meaning clear.

Comment: Please also be aware that using 'gifted' instead of 'gave' is seen as pretentious in most contexts.

Comment: I dunno, I  think gifted is hokey. It's like saying wealthy instead of rich.

Answer (score 1):

Both could be correct depending on the scenario.

Scenario 1: Your birthday. You got a car from your father, and a laptop from your mother. You could say- this is my father's gift, and that's my mother's gift. Though, a better way to say this would be- this is the gift from my father, and that's from my mother.

Scenario 2: Your father's birthday. You bought a cake and a gift. You could say- this is my father's cake, and that's my father's gift. Though, a better way to say this would be- this is the cake for my father, and that's the gift for him.

Comment: Of course, context is crucial.

Answer (score 0):

> My father gifted me a car.
>
> Having that context in mind, is it correct to write the statement
> below?
>
> "Father's Gift"

Yes, it is correct **because you have given sufficient context** to make it clear.

**Example**

I was overjoyed when Father/my father gave/gifted me a car for my birthday. Father's gift enabled me to go to and from the sports ground whenever I needed.

Note that it is more usual to say "Father/Father's gift" amongst members of the family. To a stranger you would likely say "my father/my father's gift". This is because, in the former, *Father* is being used as a name. In the latter *my father* is used as a description.

Comment: 'Having that in mind' does not imply that any _reader_ is aware of the context.